# Recycler View onClick Listerner cannot send Intent putExtas to other activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to send my string value from My recyclerview to JobDetail Activity using Recyclerview onClick Listerner. but when i use putExtra, and retrive the intent using getStringExtrast its always return null.

this is my RecyclerView adapter
**DiscoverAdapter.java**

```
public class DiscoverAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiscoverAdapter.ViewHolder>{
public List<JobPost> jobsList;
public Context context;
private Intent jobDetailActivity;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth ;
private FirebaseUser user;

public DiscoverAdapter(Context context, List<JobPost> jobsList){
    this.context = context;
    this.jobsList = jobsList;
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.job_list,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tittle_text.setText(jobsList.get(position).getTittle());
    holder.budget_text.setText(jobsList.get(position).getBudget());
    final String description = jobsList.get(position).getDescription();
    final String email = jobsList.get(position).getEmail();
    final String status = jobsList.get(position).getStatus();
    final String username = jobsList.get(position).getUsername();
    final String titlle = holder.tittle_text.getText().toString();
    final String budget = holder.budget_text.getText().toString();
    final String coba="";

    //get post id

    final String post_id = jobsList.get(position).postId;
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jobDetailActivity=null;
            int post = position;
            try {
                String current_email = user.getEmail();

                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user !=null ){
                    jobDetailActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), JobDetailActivityLogin.class);
                }





            }
            catch(Exception e){
                jobDetailActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), JobDetailActivity.class);
            }




            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("coba",coba);
            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("postId",post_id);
            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("username",username);
            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("description",description);
            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("tittle",titlle);
            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("email",email);
            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("budget",budget);
            jobDetailActivity.putExtra("status",status);
            v.getContext().startActivity(jobDetailActivity);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "CLICKED " + post_id + ", " + description + ", " + titlle + ", " + email + ", " + budget+","+status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return jobsList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public TextView tittle_text;
    public TextView budget_text;
    /**
    public TextView description_text,email_text, status_text,username_text;
    **/

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        tittle_text = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tittle_text);
        budget_text = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.budget_text);
    }
}
```

}

and this my **JobDetailActivity**

```
public class JobDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String tittle,description,status,username,budget,postId,email = "Null";
private Intent intent =getIntent();
private TextView txtTittle, txtDesc, txtStatus, txtUsername, txtBudget, txtPostId, txtEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);




    tittle= intent.getStringExtra("tittle");

    description= intent.getStringExtra("description");
    status= intent.getStringExtra("status");
    username= intent.getStringExtra("username");
    budget= intent.getStringExtra("budget");
    postId= intent.getStringExtra("postId");
    email= intent.getStringExtra("email");



    txtTittle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_detailTittle);
    txtDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
    txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
    txtUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    txtBudget = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_budget);

    txtTittle.setText(tittle);
    txtDesc.setText(description);
    txtStatus.setText(status);
    txtUsername.setText(username);
    txtBudget.setText(budget);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED " + postId + ", " + description + ", " + tittle + ", " + email + ", " + budget+","+status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();








}
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

}

this myError :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kodingsquad.lancerlots/com.example.kodingsquad.lancerlots.JobDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
tittle= intent.getStringExtra("tittle");
```

Use this

```
tittle= getIntent().getStringExtra("tittle");
```

You can use this `private Intent intent =getIntent();` upper onCreate() because intent not exist and null up there